# Python write to CSV

Tags: python, csv

i want to export user and last logs to csv file, but i recive on file only last line from connection and not all ssh response

```
import yaml
import os
import functools
import datetime


csv_file = open(filename,'w+')
csv_file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % ('name' , 'ssh_ec2user' , 'ssh_centosuser' , 'ssh_nginx_log'))
csv_file.flush()
for instance in running_instances:
    if (instance.tags == None or instance.tags == ""): continue
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if 'Name' in tag['Key']:
            name = tag['Value']
            print(name)
            instance_private_ip = (instance.private_ip_address)
            print(instance_private_ip)
ssh_ec2user = os.system("ssh -t -t -i %s -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@%s 'sudo touch last.txt;sudo  chmod 777 last.txt;sudo last > last.txt; sudo grep -v user last.txt |head -n3'" % (identity_file , instance_private_ip))
ssh_centosuser = os.system("ssh -t -t -i %s -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no centos@%s 'sudo touch last.txt;sudo  chmod 777 last.txt;sudo last > last.txt; sudo grep -v centos last.txt |head -n3'" % (identity_file , instance_private_ip))
ssh_nginx_log = "test nginx"
print(ssh_ec2user,user, ssh_nginx_log)
csv_file.write("\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\',\'%s\'\n" %(name,ssh_ec2user,ssh_centosuser,ssh_nginx_log))csv_file.flush()
```

for example per line i need to receive:
user     pts/0        172.21.0.114     Thu Jan 25 12:30 - 13:38  (01:08)
user    pts/0        172.21.2.130     Wed Jan 17 15:11 - 15:17  (00:05)
user    pts/0        172.21.2.130     Wed Jan 17 09:27 - 09:46  (00:18)
Connection to 1.1.1.1 closed.
65280 0

test nginx

and in file a only receive:
65280 0

how i can input to the same line all answer:
user     pts/0        172.21.0.114     Thu Jan 25 12:30 - 13:38  (01:08)
user    pts/0        172.21.2.130     Wed Jan 17 15:11 - 15:17  (00:05)
user    pts/0        172.21.2.130     Wed Jan 17 09:27 - 09:46  (00:18)
Connection to 1.1.1.1 closed.
65280 0

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use csv library.

```
import csv

writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

writer.writerow(['name' , 'ssh_ec2user' , 'ssh_centosuser' , 'ssh_nginx_log'])
...
writer.writerow([name,ssh_ec2user,ssh_centosuser,ssh_nginx_log])
```

The output will not be on the same line, but will be correctly escaped so that if you open it with Excel or OpenCal or similar will be displayed correctly.

Also you can have ',' characters in your string without messing up the format.

Comment: Thanks for the help.